# COM object of MSHTML doesn't copy text on an html document to clipboard on Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard, ole, mshtml

My app is written in WinApi which shows rendered HTML in its window. It uses library with COM object of mshtml for that. Copying of text on Ctrl+C is not working. Subclassed function of the control doesn't receive WM_KEYDOWN WM_CHAR messages, they consumed in mshtml. So I can't receive events of key pressing or keyboard accelerator.
I tried such ways to solve it

```
BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP(CHtmlWnd, CWnd)
ON_EVENT(CHtmlWnd, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, 259 /* DocumentComplete */, OnDocumentComplete, VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PVARIANT)
END_EVENTSINK_MAP()

void CHtmlWnd::OnDocumentComplete(LPDISPATCH pDisp, VARIANT FAR* URL)
{
    CComQIPtr<IDispatch> pHtml;
    CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pHtmlDoc;
    pHtml = m_wndBrowser.GetDocument();
    if (pHtml)
    {
        pHtml.QueryInterface(&pHtmlDoc);
    }

 ...

  if (pHtml && m_sHTML.GetLength() && pHtmlDoc)
  {
    IDispatchPtr mouseclick = EventHandler<CHtmlWnd>::CreateHandler(this, &CHtmlWnd::MouseClick, DISPID_CLICK);
    VARIANT vOnClick;
    V_VT(&vOnClick) = VT_DISPATCH;
    V_DISPATCH(&vOnClick) = mouseclick;
    pHtmlDoc->put_onclick(vOnClick);

    IDispatchPtr keyDown = EventHandler<CHtmlWnd>::CreateHandler(this, &CHtmlWnd::KeyDown, DISPID_KEYDOWN);
    VARIANT vKeyDown;
    V_VT(&vKeyDown) = VT_DISPATCH;
    V_DISPATCH(&vKeyDown) = keyDown;
    HRESULT res = pHtmlDoc->put_onkeydown(vKeyDown);
  }
}
```

Here I use document events to forward KeyDown. But defined callback function isn't invoked.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CHtmlWnd, CWnd)
  ON_WM_CREATE()
  ON_WM_DESTROY()
  ON_WM_SIZE()
  ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
  ON_WM_HOTKEY()
  ON_WM_KEYDOWN()
  ON_WM_CHAR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Also I tried this vainly.
This is my implementation of COleControlSite and IDocHostUIHandler

```
class CCustomControlSite : public COleControlSite
{
public:
    CCustomControlSite(COleControlContainer *pCnt):COleControlSite(pCnt){m_pWnd = NULL;}

    CWnd* m_pWnd; 

protected:

  DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP();
BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART(DocHostUIHandler, IDocHostUIHandler)
  STDMETHOD(ShowContextMenu)(DWORD dwID,
             POINT __RPC_FAR *ppt,
             IUnknown __RPC_FAR *pcmdtReserved,
             IDispatch __RPC_FAR *pdispReserved);

...

STDMETHOD(TranslateAccelerator)( 
            /* [in] */ LPMSG lpMsg,
            /* [in] */ const GUID __RPC_FAR *pguidCmdGroup,
            /* [in] */ DWORD nCmdID);
```

TranslateAccelerator is not invoked too.
I need get in my app a windows message like WM_CHAR or WM_KEYBOARD to solve my task. I would really appreciated for any help.

Comment: *"I need get in my app a windows message like WM_CHAR or WM_KEYBOARD to solve my task."* - That doesn't sound like a solution to your problem, which - presumably - is, to get the HTML view to respond to copy requests from the user.

Comment: In all probability you are right. How can I make to do it?

Comment: That I don't know. In all likeliness, you're going to have to go through some obscure interface, whose documentation isn't linked to any MSHTML documentation, and toggle a switch with a completely misleading name. Or maybe it's a feature you'll have to enable through the registry, like the [Clipboard Script Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser_emulation).

Comment: You can try to set a custom IDocHostUIHandler as demonstrated here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753260(v=vs.85) and implement the TranslateAccelerator method see if the keys go through it.

Comment: @Евгений Can your main window's procedure receive keyboard messges? If you can show a mini, complete and reproducible sample, it will be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you, but this hasn't work.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for advice but there is an implementation of IDocHostUIHandler::TranslateAccelerator in my code already and it is not invoked.

Comment: But do you give your IDocHostUIHandler implementation to mshtml? Are other methods of this interface invoked?

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, I do. Yes, the most of them is invoked. ShowContextMenu from sample above for expample.